# how to filter a value from list in python?

Tags: python, list

I have list of values , need to filter out values , that doesn't follow a naming convention.

like below list : list = ['a1-23','b1-24','c1-25','c1-x-25']
need to filter : all values that starts with 'c1-' , except 'c1-x-' )

> output expected: ['a1-23','b1-24','c1-x-25']

```
list = ['a1-23','b1-24','c1-25','c1-x-25']
[x for x in list if not x.startswith('c1-')]
['a1-23', 'b1-24']
```

Comment: Please try to avoid using list as a variable name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea, but you're missing the handing of values that start with `c1-x-`:

```py
[x for x in list if not x.startswith('c1-') or x.startswith('c1-x-')]
```

Comment: Just adding my solution here in comments because its similar - `[i for i in l if 'c1' not in i.split('-') or 'x' in i.split('-')]`

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

list1 = ['a1-23','b1-24','c1-25','c1-x-25',"c1-22"]
r = re.compile(r"\bc1-\b\d{2}$") # this regex matches anything with `c1-{2 digits}` exactly
[x for x in list1 if x not in list(filter(r.match,list1))]

# output
['a1-23', 'b1-24', 'c1-x-25']
```

So what my pattern does is match `EXACTLY` a word that starts with `c1-` and ends with `two` digits only.

Therefore, `list(filter(r.match,list1))` will give us all the `c1-##` and then we do a list comprehension to filter out from `list1` all the `x`'s that aren't in the new provided list containing the matches.

```
x for x in [1,2,3] if x not in [1,2]
#output
[3]
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: @wscourge will do